# What does it mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Watching the middle-aged Jimmy Connors defeat the middle-aged Martina
>   Navratilova at Las Vegas last week, was not so much a tennis match as a fracas in the
>   sex war.
>   The 14,000 audience was split along gender lines with each victorious shot being
>   acclaimed as proof of either male superiority or female equality.
>   In the end, even though Connors was handicapped by having only one ball to serve
>   and a 3ft wider court to receive in, he walked off with $500,000 prize money by
>   vindicating the obvious: that at the top level of tennis men are faster and more
>   powerful than women. Feminists have only God to blame for this unfairness.

Could you explain the last sentence 'Feminists have only God to blame for this unfairness'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the physical advantage/superiority that men have over women is inherently due to nature (or equivalently, God), and not due to any human social construct. Feminists who sought to show that the disparity in athletic performance could be eliminated by setting everything else equal, found that the disparity was still there, so could not attribute it to any such factor which was supposedly equalized. The only difference remaining was how God made them, so only God is to blame.